# Maximum DataPoint limit for Geographical Map visualization in AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am new to QuickSight and trying to do a PoC with QuickSight.
While trying to develop a geographical map visualization, I noticed that it limits to 5000 top data points in the visualizations.
From below link I understand this display limit of QuickSight.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/working-with-visual-types.html#customizing-number-of-data-points?icmpid=docs-quicksight-whatsnew
Is 5000 is the maximum data-points for a geographical map? (I couldn't find the maximum limit for map in documentations)
Is there a way to increase this limit as we have pretty bigger dataset and may not filter out data down till 5000 datasets.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I checked and confirm that there is no statement about the limit of the geo map in the official documentation. Judging on my works with QuickSight until now, the limit is highly possible at 5000, which is the limits of line chart, bar chart, combo chart and some others.

In our use case with not-geo-map chart, we aggregate the data higher to reduce the number of data points, for example from daily data to weekly data. This is not a solution I enjoy with, but have to compromise.